# Error message: 'TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object' while trying to append date value to a empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a panda series with Timestamp values. But i am getting below error. While trying to append timestamp value to empty dataframe.

```
x = pd.Series()
dfx = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('month')} 
for k in dfx:
   x.append(dfx[k].iloc[0,0])
```

value of df:

```
         Date                        Value      month   year
 0      2007-05-25                   0.3992     5       2007
 1      2007-11-06                   0.3936     11      2007
 2      2007-11-07                   0.2039     11      2007 
 3      2009-01-14                   0.2881     1       2009
 4      2009-02-06                   0.0375     2       2009
 5      2009-05-07                   0.3217     5       2009
 6      2009-08-06                   0.4060     8       2009
```

Error Message:

> raise TypeError("cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object") TypeError:
>   cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Can anyone help solve issue.

Expected output:

```
          Date                        
   0      2007-05-25                   
   1      2007-11-06                 
   2      2009-01-14                   
   3      2009-02-06                   
   4      2009-05-07                 
   5      2009-08-06
```

Comment: I think there's a mistake with your expected output? `2009-05-07 ` shouldn't be there. Your current solution does not yield it.

Comment: `2009-05-07` should be there. Because its grouping by month.

Comment: Your question is unclear, you have not made your intentions clear nor explained what you are trying to do. This seems to be a pattern with you and is very frustrating. This is the second time I've had to delete my answer because of a misunderstanding with a poorly formed question.

Comment: I have changed my code to first date of every month using `groupby(['year', 'month'])` . So issue is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue using following code.

```
   x= df.groupby(['year', 'month']).Date.head(1)
```

Comment: It seems like the only change to my answer was adding 'year' to groupby?

Comment: Yes. Before was two for loops for getting the first date value of each month. groupby simplified the process. Thanks for helping.